# My search button is "not active" and unable to work why?

Tags: search, header, shopping-cart

The search field and verbiage is there however you are not able to type in the search box, the go button does nothing.

I have tried to review code but I'm not a code person at all.

```
<div class="sf_search"> <div class="widget quick-search"> <div class="widget_content"> <form id="searchQuickForm" method="get" action="shop.bohbeauty.com/searchquick-submit.sc"> <div class="form_item"> <input placeholder="Search our products..." type="text" name="keywords" value="" id="searchtext" class="input" /> </div> <div class="form_button"> <input type="submit" value="Go!" class="quick-search-button btn" /> </div>
```

I expect to be able to be a client and search products on my site

Comment: <div class="sf_search">    
    <div class="widget quick-search">
        <div class="widget_content">
            <form id="searchQuickForm" method="get" action="http://www.shop.bohbeauty.com/searchquick-submit.sc">
                <div class="form_item">
                    <input placeholder="Search our products..." type="text" name="keywords" value="" id="searchtext" class="input" />              
                </div>
                <div class="form_button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Go!" class="quick-search-button btn" />
                </div>

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the action attribute in `<form id="searchQuickForm" method="get" action="shop.bohbeauty.com/searchquick-submit.sc">` should be prefixed by http://.

So your script should be like this instead
`<form id="searchQuickForm" method="get" action="http://shop.bohbeauty.com/searchquick-submit.sc">`